# How to jump a row in a while loop if condition met

Tags: php, while-loop

I have created a form which managers can create users for the system. I have a separate table which contains user types Ex: Admin, Manager ... etc.

I use a while loop in my form to drag the above mentioned user roles from the table and draw a set of radio buttons.

My problem is I want to hid the Admin option from the normal manager I used `PHP` but it only hides the radio button it self not the text next to it my code is below.

Code:

```
<div id="userRoles">
 <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
  <?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
   <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles"
    value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>" <?php if ($_SESSION["uRole"] == "1" && $row["userRole"] == "Admin" ){?> hidden <?php } ?>><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }?>
</div>
```

I'm thinking of making the while loop skip that 1st line using an IF ... ELSE but I can't get my head around how to do it.

I just want to hide the Admin option.

**UPDATE:** With the help of mplungjan and Alive to Die I got this problem solved I used the continue method which was more streamline from my point of view now my code looks like this;

Code:

```
<div id="userRoles">
 <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
 <?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if ($_SESSION["uRole"] !== "1" && $row["userRole"] == "Admin" ) continue ?>
  <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }?>
</div>
```

Comment: if ($row["userRole"] == "Admin") [continue;](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: means you don't want radio button which contain admin when manager login ??

Comment: @mplungjan I did have look at PHP Continue before posting my issue I was unable to understand how to use it. So if I use your suggestion will the loop continue from the 2nd line ?

Comment: @JagdishChaudhary Radio button and the text following it my attempt above only hides the radio button not the text.

Comment: `continue` statement basically says: jump immediately to the loop's closing `}` - where it will "continue" with the next iteration or stop if it's at the end of the iteration (in the case of a `while` it will go back to check the condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if and [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) - statements after the continue are ignored

use OR (||) if either uRole==1 or Admin should be skipped

```
<?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
   if ($_SESSION["uRole"]=="1" && $row["userRole"] == "Admin") continue; // ignore the rest of the loop
?>
    <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }}?>
}?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and for showing me something new which I didn't know. I understood how to use the continue function after reading the manual twice. And I use &&  so the condition have to match both.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do like This-

```
<div id="userRoles">
<label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
<?php

 while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
    if($_SESSION["uRole"] == "1" && $row["userRole"] != "Admin" ))
    {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="userRoles" value="'.$row["urId"].'">'.$row["userRole"].'';
    }
 }
?> 
</div>
```

Comment: @Alive to Die was wondering why your post got removed thought I made you upset by unselecting the answer as the best answer. But I can see both answer are the same.

Comment: very friendly of @AliveToDie since he was in fact 5 minutes earlier.